# Пунктуационное выделение присоединительного оборота

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Друзья мои, а нужна ли здесь запятая?

**В последнее время возникла тенденция к уменьшению аудиторной нагрузки в программах обучения, с увеличением часов на «самостоятельную работу».**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы определили, что слова "с увеличением часов на «самостоятельную работу»" являются присоединительным оборотом — и я с этим согласен. Такие обороты как правило  выделяются запятыми. Более того, при отсутствии запятой получим "программы обучения с увеличением часов на «самостоятельную работу»" — а это не то, что автор имел в виду.

И еще два замечания.

(1) Мне непонятно, почему слова *самостоятельную работу* взяты в кавычки. Это выражает скептическое отношение автора или цитируется первоисточник?

(2) Для усиления фразы я бы добавил слово *одновременным*:  "...тенденция к уменьшению аудиторной нагрузки ..., с одновременным увеличением часов..."

Comment: Скептическое отношение автора, я полагаю... Спасибо большое за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Я  это предложение написала бы так:

**В последнее время возникла тенденция к уменьшению аудиторной нагрузки в программах обучения с  одновременным увеличением  часов на «самостоятельную работу».**

Оборот **не очень похож на присоединительную  конструкцию** с дополнительными сведениями, информация скорее одного порядка важности. Соответственно, запятая в этом случае не ставится.

Comment: Согласен с вами!

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, мне Ваш ответ тоже кажется правильным, особенно с добавлением слова **одновременным**... Тут очевидно какое-то противоречие, нужно смотреть по смыслу...

Comment: В Нацкорпусе можно найти примеры с выделением подобных  оборотов и без. Пример с выделением: *Формирование колонки заряда в полиэтиленовом рукаве от устья скважины, с одновременным погружением ее в обводненную скважину, возможно при создании необходимых условий принудительной подачи формируемого заряда в обводненную часть скважины*. [Совершенствование буровзрывных работ на Донском ГОКе // «Горная промышленность», 2004] ----    Меня смущает то, что при отсутствии запятой оборот может быть отнесен к "программам обучения", а не к "тенденции" .